# Libgdx - check collisions between actors

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a `Stage` with several `Actors`. I want to check collision between each of them. I have a functionality for checking collision between two actors. But when I implement a loop, then in second time first loop is about to happend the app crashes.

```
@Override
public void render() {
    for (Actor actor : stage.getActors()) {
        if (actor instanceof Followable) {
           ((Followable) actor).setCurrentPosition(player);
        }

        for (Actor collidableActor : stage.getActors()) {
            //check for collision here
        }
    }
//...
}
```

As I said the app crashes when first loop is happening for the second time. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Could we get some logs to help you ? Is it a null pointer exception or something else ?

Comment: How many actors you have ?